# Implementing FordAlgorithm to computer the shortest path

Tags: algorithm, bellman-ford

The following code is from FordAlgorithm which will find the Shortest path from source to another node (or destination).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;


struct wde{ // a weighted directed edge
    char s, d;
    int w;
};

const int INF = 9999;
char noPred = ' ';
struct label{
    char vertex;
    int currDist;
    char predecessor;
    label(){}
    label(const label& other){
        cout << "Copy constructor called\n";
        vertex = other.vertex;
        currDist = other.currDist;
        predecessor = other.predecessor;
    }
    label(char v, int d, char p) :vertex(v), currDist(d), predecessor(p){}
    bool operator==(const label other){
        return vertex == other.vertex;
    }
};

class compareLabels{
public:
    bool operator() (label* lhs, const label* rhs) const{
        return (lhs->currDist < rhs->currDist);
    }
};
list<label*> myqp;

wde EL[] = { // 12 edges (we were originally missing a->h
    { 'c', 'd', 1 }, { 'c', 'g', 1 }, { 'c', 'h', 1 },
    { 'h', 'g', -1 }, { 'g', 'd', -1 }, { 'd', 'a', 2 },
    { 'd', 'e', 4 }, { 'd', 'i', 1 }, { 'a', 'b', 1 },
    { 'b', 'e', -5 }, { 'e', 'f', 4 }, { 'i', 'f', 1 }};

int infAdd(int a, int b){
    if (a == INF || b == INF)
        return INF;
    else
        return a + b;
}
void ShortestPath(int ne, wde elist[], char first){
    int i, ui, nv, wt, dist1, dist2, dist3;
    // Determine the set of vertices from the edge list
    set<char> vertices;
    for (i = 0; i < ne; i++){ //look at each edge
        vertices.insert(elist[i].s);
        vertices.insert(elist[i].d);
    }
    cout << "We found " << (nv = vertices.size()) << " vertices\n";

    // Set up the adjacency matrix
    vector<vector<int>> adjmat(nv, vector<int>(nv, 0));
    const int asa = int('a'); // char 'a' as an ascii value

    // Set up the labels and store in a 'priority queue'
    vector<label> labels(nv);
    for each (char ch in vertices){
        labels[int(ch) - asa] = label(ch, INF, noPred);
    }


    labels[int(first) - asa].currDist = 0;
    list<label*> toBeChecked; // pointers to labels
    //toBeChecked.assign = first;

    for (i = 0; i < ne; i++){
        wde &e = elist[i]; // refer to elist[i]
        adjmat[int(e.s) - asa][int(e.d) - asa] = e.w;
    }
```

I think the problem begins from here:

```
    // FordAlgorithm*******************************************
    for (i = 1; i <= nv - 1; i++){
        dist1 = labels[first].currDist;
        for (ui = 0; ui < nv; ui++){

            dist2 = labels[ui].currDist;
            if ((wt = adjmat[first][ui]) != 0)
            {
                dist3 = infAdd(dist1, wt);
                if (dist2 > dist3){
                    labels[ui].currDist = dist3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
cout << "The shortest distances from " << first << " to each vertex:\n";
    stack<char> path;
    char v;
    for (i = 0; i < nv; i++){  // each of the destinations
        cout << labels[i].vertex << " " << labels[i].currDist << endl;
        v = labels[i].vertex;
        // put the code you're given
        // in the first while loop, we follow the predecssors back
        // from the "sink" to the "source"
    }
}


int main(void){
    int nedges = sizeof(EL) / sizeof(wde);
    cout << "We have " << nedges << " edges\n";
    ShortestPath(nedges, EL, 'c');
    cout << "done\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The program built successfully. However, it has error: vector subscript out of range when debugging it. Do you guys have any ideas why this happened? Thanks.

Comment: You have to use tag of this languge instead of using algorithm's tag

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Also include the results of your debugging attempts.  "I think the problem begins from here" has no hard data for us to use.